# Angular 2 data model inheritance

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have following setup in my angular2 and asp.net core project:

I have an c# .net core api's that returns this classes:

```
public class fighter
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public datetime birthdate { get; set; }
  public string score { get; set; }
}


public class fight
{
  public int id { get; set }
  public fighter host { get; set }
  public fighter guest { get; set }
  public string venue { get; set }
}
```

Inside my fighter.component.ts file, i have this code that binds api response to actual page:

```
interface Fighter {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  birthdate: string;
  score: string;
}
```

How can i bind my `fight()` class to a fight.component.ts? 
There's no master-detail relationship between components, i just wan't to show all "fights" that api returns.

Comment: First off, C# classes don't have () after the class name. Second; could you be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish? I read this as you basically have the answer already... you just create an interface for the `fight` class similar to your `fighter`

Comment: How do i inherit Fighter{} interface from fighter.component.ts file in Fight{} interface in fight.component.ts? That's question..

Comment: Even though this page is about MAster/Detail, if you stop after "Displaying heroes in a template" you should be done https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if what you are after is having a strong type or contract for the model that you are getting back for your API, you could have the following interface for your Fight class.

```
interface Fight {
    id: number;
    host: Fighter;
    guest: Fighter;
    venue: string;
}
export default Fight;
```

Now, from your comments I think the issue here is that you don't know how to import the actual type from one file to another. When declaring your interface, you need to export it. So lets say your `Fighter` interface lives in a file called `IFighter.ts`. That file would look something like.

```
interface Fighter {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  birthdate: string;
  score: string;
}

export default Fighter; <= Note
```

Then to import this interface to be used in another file you need to do

```
// fight.component.ts
import Fighter from 'relative/path/to/IFighter/file';
import Fight from 'relative/path/to/IFight/file';

// Do mappings.
```

You might want to read a bit on Javascript Modules, Hope this clarifies things?

Comment: I just started learning angular and what i'm actually trying to acomplish here is something like ViewModel i .net C# which contains a property from a db class (fighter) and few other "generic type (int, string, datetime, etc...) " properties

Comment: Angular doesn't really support the MVVM pattern that you are after, it was originally based on MVC and now its using a component approach, what you would want is a component property that can bind to the view, which in this case is a `Fight` or a collection of `Fight` i.e. `public fights: Fight[]`. any `public` properties that you define in your component class will be accessible to the view. If you need to render a collection on the view you'll need an `ngFor` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: If you include your fight.component.ts code I can try to help clarify things.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño I don't know, it feels pretty MVVM-y to me :)